# Verifying example of product of elements of finite order having infinite order

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove that there exists an example of a non-abelian group with elements of finite order whose product is infinite. The question has been asked elsewhere, but I was not able to fully verify the answer from reading the replies, and was hoping someone could check over my logic.

The example that keeps surfacing is the set of elements such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. If $G$ is abelian, $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2 = ee = e$. If not, we may get a different element each time.

I do not understand this answer for the following reasons. First, though I know that I want to find a group with two such elements of order $2$, can I just refer to a 'group with such elements'? $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the first that comes to mind, or even $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but both are abelian.

A hint on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: “The set of elements such that $a^2+b^2=1$” doesn’t really make much sense in the context of a group; you only have one operation, either addition or multiplication; here you are using two of them. I do agree you are confused, so perhaps you should the example you claim you are seeing surface a lot...